# Why Post Data in Jmeter is going as --1Ls95bBrGMOsS5H7hQGp9_uJf_Z50M7-vQR-- when i am sending {"employee":"622083"}

Tags: json, jmeter

I am using below url to send multiple request via json file

https://www.testingexcellence.com/jmeter-tutorial-how-to-send-a-json-file-as-request-in-body/

I put ${__FileToString(C:\PStech\${__eval(${JSON_FILE})}.txt,,)} in Body Data of Http request of Jmeter and using csv to send multiple json files which here I stored as 100.txt and 101.txt.

But I see Request is going as below

POST data:
--1Ls95bBrGMOsS5H7hQGp9_uJf_Z50M7-vQR--

Ideally it should send Request as {"employee":"622083"}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1FZe.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mdt8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUSqM.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to untick `Use multipart/form-data for HTTP POST` box in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

Instead of this add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

More information: [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right)